# My input in if statement is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

My input in my if statement is not working. I am using Python3 and the problem is at the first if statement in the defined function.

```
import random

random1 = random.randint(1, 11)
random2 = random.randint(1, 11)
correct = random1 * random2
list_of_correct = []
list_of_wrong = []


def ex():
    proceed = input("Proceed?: ")
    if proceed.lower == "yes":
        ans = input("What is " + str(random1) + " * " + str(random2) + "?: ")
        if int(ans) == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            list_of_correct.append(str(random1 + ":" + str(random2) + ":" + str(ans)))
            print(ex())
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            list_of_wrong.append(str(random1) + ":" + str(random2) + ":" + str(ans))
    elif proceed.lower == "mfm":
        print(list_of_correct)
        print(list_of_wrong)


print(ex())
```

Answer (score 4):

You compare a function `proceed.lower` against a string `'yes'` - they are never the same.

You need to call the function:

```
if proceed.lower() == "yes":
```

to convert your input to lower case for your comparison.

```
print("".lower) # <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fc134277508>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code

```
import random

random1 = random.randint(1, 11)
random2 = random.randint(1, 11)
correct = random1 * random2
list_of_correct = []
list_of_wrong = []


def ex():
    proceed = input("Proceed?: ")
    if proceed.lower() == "yes":
        ans = input("What is " + str(random1) + " * " + str(random2) + "?: ")
        if int(ans) == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            list_of_correct.append(str(random1 + ":" + str(random2) + ":" + str(ans)))
            print(ex())
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            list_of_wrong.append(str(random1) + ":" + str(random2) + ":" + str(ans))
    elif proceed.lower() == "mfm":
        print(list_of_correct)
        print(list_of_wrong)


print(ex())
```

Comment: Updated a typo. @wjandrea.